# SSIS Conditional Split - Operation Failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I wanted to learn the conditional split in SSIS. Therefore, I took the first 100 IDs from a column and wanted to split them into two groups:
Small_ids: all IDs < 50
Big_ids: all IDSs >= 50

However, I am getting this error message when I want to connect to the output source:

[image: Conditional Split operation failure]

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would only have 1 test:
ID < 50

the rest would be default output which you can rename to BIG.

You really haven't given enough information to solve your real problem though.

Is the source configured with a SQL statement? The error is an error where no metadata is present.

Also, please try not to use pictures and when you do you should take the pertinent information out of the image and put in text. You will open up your answer pool to a greater audience as there are a few that can't see image links from work computer.